# Spotify API Post call – Response 415?

Tags: python, api, post, spotify

Using Python, I'm trying to do a POST call to the Spotify API by following the instructions under the paragraph Client Credentials Flow at the link https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#client_credentials_flow and this is the code I have come up with.

However, I get `Response [415]` when I run it. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
import pprint
import requests
import urllib2
import json
import base64

client_id='b040c4e03217489aa647c055265d0ac'
client_secret='2c2928bb7d3e43278424002d2e8bda46b'
authorization_param='Basic ' + base64.standard_b64encode(client_id + ':' + client_secret)
grant_type='client_credentials'

#Request based on Client Credentials Flow from https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/

#Header must be a base 64 encoded string that contains the client ID and client secret key. 
#The field must have the format: Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded client_id:client_secret>
header_params={'Authorization' : authorization_param}

#Request body parameter: grant_type Value: Required. Set it to client_credentials
 body_params = {'grant_type' : grant_type}

url='https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'

response=requests.post(url, header_params,    body_params) # POST request takes both headers and body parameters
print response
```

Comment: a status of 400 is what you want?

Comment: no...400 is bad request. I need 200

Comment: `header_params={'Authorization' : authorization_param,'grant_type' : grant_type}`  `response=requests.post(url, header_params)`
try this

Comment: Doesn't work - that gives me response 400....we want a response 200...

Comment: Are you sure your client id is correct? I checked the return text and it says the client id is invalid.

Comment: i changed the client_id and secret so I could keep it private - so that part is normal

Answer (score 10):

The type of authentication that Spotify is requesting is just basic HTTP authentication. This is a standardised form of authentication which you can read more about [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). The requests library supports basic authentication without requiring you to create the headers yourself. See the [python requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/#basic-authentication) for information.

The code below uses the request library authentication to connect to the Spotify API.

```
import requests

client_id = # Enter your client id here
client_secret = # Enter your client secret here

grant_type = 'client_credentials'

#Request based on Client Credentials Flow from https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/

#Request body parameter: grant_type Value: Required. Set it to client_credentials
body_params = {'grant_type' : grant_type}

url='https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'

response=requests.post(url, data=body_params, auth = (client_id, client_secret)) 
print response
```

I created a test account with Spotify and created a test client id and client secret which worked find for this. I got a response 200 back using python 2.7.6 and requests 2.2.1.

Comment: Please set mpursuit's answer as the correct one, it'll be clear that this question has been answered correctly and will of course give him/her some of those sweet, sweet, points.